# How can I use multiprocessing to add lots of pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a list of about 1million dataframes and I would need to add all of them, and I believe that multiprocessing would be faster but I don't know how to tackle the problem.

I was thinking spawning n processes, each process take 2 elements in the list, add them one another, remove them from the list and add back the result to the list.
keep going until there is only one element in the list.
Is it a good way to go?
Thanks

```py
result = pd.DataFrame()
for mydf in list_df:
   result = result.add(mydf, fille_value=0)
```

Comment: No, pairwise reductions are very slow. Best to place them all in a queue and perform a single concat step, assuming you have the memory for it.

Comment: How do you get these dataframes? Have you considered `dask`?